# Hdfs equivalent of snapshotdiff and createsnapshot in Gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hdfs

We are migrating our existing jobs from Hadoop to GCP. 
I encountered two hdfs functions **createSnapshot** and **snapshotDiff** in our existing hadoop code. Do we have thier equivalent in GCP?

Comment: Do you use Cloud Dataproc?

Comment: yes. We do use cloud dataproc.

Answer (score 0):

Table format projects `Delta Lake` and `Apache Iceberg` are now available in the latest version of Cloud Dataproc (version 1.5 Preview).

With these table formats, you can now use Dataproc for workloads that need:

- ACID transaction
- Data versioning (a.k.a. time travel)
- Schema enforcement
- Schema evolution and more

Data versioning provides a snapshot of your data in history. You can look up data history and roll back to the data at a certain time or version in history.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/getting-started-with-new-table-formats-on-dataproc). I hope it helps.